# How to fix curtain rod to split door casing

Tags: door-frame

I need at least a temporary solution to get this curtain rod fixed back to my basement door trim. Going to be redoing all this here as soon as I find a contractor, but I need an immediate solution if there is one.

The rod has been pulled and the door frame is splintering. Any advice appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Move both ends down a half a inch and screw back in.

Comment: It's generally not wise (or pretty) to mount hardware to moldings. Extend the rod and mount it to the wall.

Comment: Unless there's no stud just outside the trim.

Comment: There's clearly a stud there which can be reached at an angle, and hollow-wall anchors would hold well in the paneling.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea. I'll see if I can find a stud or use wall anchors. The paneling down there is quite loose. I'll be replacing it all with drywall this year (hopefully)

Comment: Old school paneling like that is hung on furring strips; you wont find studs. That's what you keep missing if it keeps pulling out. Use those nail heads in the paneling to tell you where to go.

Comment: ... furring strips standing proud, so your target area is 3/4", and if you miss there's nothing for about a 1-1/2", and then drywall, or if you're lucky: plaster, so there's eventually lath ... meaning as per usual use 3" exterior screws for everything.

Answer (score 1):

There is a stud right there.  Use it.

1. Just tap/bang/patch/glue/fill the trim back together as best you can.  It doesn't have to be perfect.   If you have the paint, paint it otherwise use a crayon or a marker .. again, as best you can. It'll be covered up by the bracket.
2. Use 2" or 2-1/2" screws.  Drill pilot holes all the way into the stud.  Then drill bigger holes into the now-patched trim, big enough for the screw to pass through without turning.     Screw the bracket into the stud.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is to move the entire mount (on both sides) down until the screws will go into solid wood.

The correct solution is to replace the top piece of trim then remount the curtain rod supports lower anyway. I'd imagine that part of the problem was because the mounts were tipped downward because the top of the mount was on a thicker part of the trim. Every movement of the curtain puts force on the screws holding it up, but, because of the angle, they put extra force on that top screw, causing it to pull out.

Replacing the trim isn't really a difficult job and is something you could do with just a small selection of hand tools, if you wanted to. Feel free to ask another question about how to go about doing that. Even better, search the questions first, as there's probably already a question that'll get you 99% of the way there.